# How can I filter a datetime with a date in Tortoise-ORM?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I am creating an application in fastapi and I am using Tortoise-ORM as orm. I have the following model:

```
from tortoise import fields

from app.models.base_class import Base


class Announcement(Base):
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=64, null=False)
    description = fields.TextField()
    date = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now=True)

    # ORM relationship between Announcement and User entity
    user = fields.ForeignKeyField(
        "models.User",
        related_name="announcements",
        on_delete=fields.CASCADE
    )
```

And I need to get all the "announcements" of the current day, the problem is that my date field is of type datetime and I want to filter by day (without considering the time). How can I do this with tortoise-orm? something like this:

```
 async def get_today_announcement(self):
     today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
     return await self.model.filter(date=today).all()
```

(The above does not work since it returns an empty list when the hours do not match).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
async def get_today_announcement(self):
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        return await self.model.filter(
            date__year=today.year,
            date__month=today.month,
            date__day=today.day
            ).all()
```